# Why this C++ code works the way it works?

Tags: c++

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
     char *name = "Stack overflow";

     cout << *&name << endl;
     cout << &*name << endl;    // I don't understand why this works

     return 0;
 }
```

I understand how the first "cout" statement works but unable to understand why and how the second one works.

Comment: Why is it any more confusing than the first one?

Comment: Please don't use `char *` to point to a non-modifiable string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` and `*` are opposite operations. The first one takes the address of the array (adding one level of indirection) and then dereferences it (removing one level of indirection). The second dereferences the pointer (removing one level of indirection) and then takes the address of the result (adding one). Either way, you get back to the same value.

Just like 4 / 2 * 2 is the same as 4 * 2 / 2, or just like taking a step back and then forward leaves you at the same place as taking a step forward and then backward.

Comment: Unless you're operating on, say, a null pointer. Then the second has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chris: Interestingly, C explicitly allows `&*p` where `p` is `NULL`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, That *is* interesting. Especially since C++ doesn't AFAICT.

Comment: @chris: Yeah, it's a footnote in C99 section 6.5.3.2.  I've never found anything equivalent in C++ standards.

Answer (score 2):

To understand how the second statement works substitute it

```
cout << &*name << endl;
```

for

```
cout << &name[0] << endl;
```

because *name and name[0] are equivalent and return reference to (lvalue) the first character of the string literal pointed by name.

The last statement is equivalent to

```
cout << name << endl;
```

Comment: Are you really from Moscow?

Comment: Yes, I am. Otherwise I would not point out Moscow.:) I mean that Moscow is the capital of Russia. It is not the town with the same name in USA.:)

Comment: I didn't even know there _was_ a Moscow in the USA, not that I'm surprised upon hearing of it. But, really, I don't live in orbit so one has to take a slight pinch of salt with these things.